# How to display all JSON key and value without using key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It maybe basic, but i'm stuck of how to display JSON file in react native
For example, i'm get a json object by

```
const [post, setPost] = React.useState(null);
  const baseURL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(baseURL).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setPost(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

And it return like

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Now i want to display on screen something like

```
   1
   1,
   sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit,
  quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto
```

I know, i can use `post.userId` or `post.id` to display each of them, but if i have 1000 items like this, how can i display them without call keys?
i tried

```
{Object.keys(post).map(i => (
          <Text>{i}</Text>
        ))}
```

But it return something like

```
{
    "userId"
    "id"
    "title"
    "body"
}
```

So how can I display data instead of key without using key?

Comment: You mean `Object.values(obj)`?

Comment: Asked and answered 10 years ago, answer updated to today's versions of ECMAScript...

Comment: Aside: having 1000 items on screen isn't great UX. You should look into pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the enumerable property values and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the resulting array into a string:

```js
const obj = {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}

const res = Object.values(obj).join('\n')

console.log(res)
```

Your [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) approach is also fine - you'll just need to get the value of the property:

```js
const obj = {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}

const res = Object.keys(obj).map(i => obj[i]).join('\n')

console.log(res)
```